# How to fetch the offset stored in zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

Needs to generate Consumer Lag Metrics for our application (Kafka 0.10) in which offsets are stored in zookeeper.  Looking for Java API or other ways to fetch offsets stored in zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying from command line, you can use kafka-consumer-groups.sh script in following way.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker> --describe --group <group-name>
```

It will return the data in following way:

```
    TOPIC       PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET      LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
testtopic-1         0          13164704        13164773        69         test-consumer-bf8d1655-63a6-4061-b680-0f11cdf182e5/100.96.67.0                     test-consumer              
testtopic-1         1          13161581        13161650        69         test-consumer-agent-bf8d1655-63a6-4061-b680-0f11cdf182e5/100.96.67.0               test-consumer   
testtopic-1         2          12229509        12229578        69         test-consumer-bf8d1655-63a6-4061-b680-0f11cdf182e5/100.96.67.0                     test-consumer
testtopic-1         3          86              86              0          test-consumer-agent-bf8d1655-63a6-4061-b680-0f11cdf182e5/100.96.67.0               test-consumer
```

If you are using java, you can use `AdminClient.describeConsumerGroups` method below :

http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nishu for your suggestion.  Since we are looking for offsets stored in zookeeper, we needs to use
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper  --describe --group

Corresponding Scala API is available in the core implementation of

[ConsumerGroupCommand.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)